# How to ofstream a numeric value in a .txt file and read same data through ifstream in same program

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string mobile;
    int N[10];
    ofstream file;
    file.open("my.txt");
    cout<<"enter mobile ";
    getline(cin, mobile);
    file<<mobile<<endl;
    cout<<"enter number ";
    cin>>N[10];
    file<<N;
    file.close();
    int a;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"press 1 to know details ";
    cin>>a;
    if(a==1)
    {
        ifstream file1;
        file1.open("my.txt");
        string str;
        int num;
        file1>>str;
        file1>>num;
        cout<<"company "<<str<<endl<<"number  "<<num;
        file1.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

string value is stored and read perfectly but the integer value entered is stored in the form of 0x61fdf0  and when it is supposed to again print, it always prints 0. I am trying to store a mobile number.

I am coding in code blocks.

Comment: And what did the debugger say?

Comment: Any special reason to use getline? why not std::cin >> mobile?

Comment: `cin>>N[10]` exhibits undefined behavior: valid indexes into an array `int N[10]` are 0 through 9. `file<<N` does not write an integer to the file - it writes the pointer value, the address of the first element of the `N` array.

Comment: no special reason to use getline. I

Comment: @d4rk4ng31: getline reads up to the end of the line while `cin >> mobile` will stop at the first blank. I cannot know which is required here but there are different ways for different use cases.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, *there are different ways for different use cases*... exactly my point. They **need** to be used in different use cases and interchange should be avoided. In this case, a mobile number is needed, which does not have a space (unless the format needs to be changed for some particular reason). That is why I suggested `cin`.

Comment: However, from the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326306/how-to-ofstream-a-numeric-value-in-a-txt-file-and-read-same-data-through-ifstre?noredirect=1#comment115490422_65326306) made, I think OP needs to know the difference and the proper use cases where they are supposed to use the different ways, and also, the need to do so.  *getline reads up to the end of the line while cin >> mobile will stop at the first blank* @ARJUN, please take note. This line is very important for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int NUM = 10;

int main()
{
    string mobile;
    int n[NUM];
    ofstream file;
    file.open("my.txt");
    cout << "enter mobile: ";
    getline(cin, mobile);
    file << mobile << endl;
    cout << "enter number ";
    file << n[0];
    file.close();
    int a;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "press 1 to know details ";
    cin >> a;
    if(a==1)
    {
        ifstream file1;
        file1.open("my.txt");
        string str;
        int num;
        (file1, str);
        file1 >> num;
        cout << "company: " << str <<"\nnumber: " << num << endl;
        file1.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cin>>N[10]; attemps to assign integer to variable location that doesn't exist, producing an error. Remember array begin at 0, hence an array of 10 elements is 0-9, 9 being the 10th element.

Comment: file<<N; This assigns the address of the start of the N array and its likely what displays when you try to print the integer in your program. Use N[I], i being the array index location you want to store in the file, next time.